# Which context.xml is used First

Tags: java, tomcat, context.xml, meta-inf

On my `Tomcat 6.0.x` I have a `context.xml` file in the `conf` directory and I also have a `context.xml` in the `META-INF` directory of a project deployed from `netbeans6.9.1`.

The `context.xml` contains the details of database to be connected...

Which among the two will be used by the application to connect to the database

- Context.xml in `tomcat/conf`
- Context.xml in `project/META-INF`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that `tomcat/conf/context.xml` defines a set of "global", statically-configured contexts. Any WAR deployed with its own `context.xml` will be configured using that, rather than any of the contexts defined in the global one.